# Python/Pandas for loop through a list only working on the last item in the list

Tags: python, pandas

This is a bit strange to me...

I have a DataFrame with a 'utility' column and an 'envelope' column.

I have a list of cities that get sent special envelopes:
`['Chicago', 'New York', 'Dallas', 'LA']`

I need to loop through each value in the utility column, check if it's in the list of cities that get sent special envelopes, and if it is, add the utility name to the envelope column.

This is the code I wrote to do that:

```py
utilityEnv = ['Chicago', 'New York', 'Dallas', 'LA']
for i in utilityEnv :
    print(i)
    for j in df.index :
        if i in df.at[j, 'utility'] :
            print('true')
            df.at[j, 'envelope'] = df.at[j, 'utility']
        else :
            df.at[j, 'envelope'] = 'ABF'
```

When I run this code, it prints the utility name, then a bunch of 'true'-s for each utility as it's supposed to each time it's going to set the envelope column to equal the utility column, but, the final df shows that the envelope columns were set to equal the utility column ONLY for LA, and not for any of the other cities. Even though there are many 'true'-s printed for the other utilities which means it made it into that block for other utilities as well.

For example:

This is what happens:

```
          utility                 envelope
0      Chicago                 ABF
1      New York               ABF
2      Austin                    ABF
3      Sacramento         ABF
4      Boston                  ABF
5      LA                          LA
6      Dallas                   ABF
7      LA                          LA
8      Chicago               ABF
9      Austin                  ABF
```

This is what supposed to happen:

```
          utility                 envelope
0      Chicago                 Chicago
1      New York               New york
2      Austin                    ABF
3      Sacramento         ABF
4      Boston                  ABF
5      LA                          LA
6      Dallas                   Dallas
7      LA                          LA
8      Chicago               Chicago
9      Austin                  ABF
```

Sorry about the formatting I had to do it on my phone

Any idea why this is happening??

Comment: please show example of yuor dataframe and expected output

Comment: Added the dataframe and expected output

Comment: please check answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) with [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html)

```
df['envelope']=df['utility'].where(df['utility'].isin(utilityEnv), 'ABF')
```

**Output**

```
      utility  envelope
0     Chicago   Chicago
1    New York  New York
2      Austin       ABF
3  Sacramento       ABF
4      Boston       ABF
5          LA        LA
6      Dallas    Dallas
7          LA        LA
8     Chicago   Chicago
9      Austin       ABF
```

**This is much faster than using loops, panda methods are created for these things.**

Here I show you 
a correct code with loops but you should not use this

```
for i in df.index:
    val = df.at[i,'utility']
    if val in utilityEnv:
        df.at[i,'envelop']=val
    else:
        df.at[i,'envelop']='ABF'
```